# How To fix Timeouting Test In Arquilian

Tags: java

I'm kind new of arquilian and i wanna know is there a fix of timeouting test in arquilian,
I see that when doing test it takes more time, and I need to see is there a new solution to run multiple tests using a single deployment archive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wanna know how to do multiple test with one deployment archive in arquilian